# I'm conecting on mysql, using MySQL Workbench, but when i try in visual studio i get the message "Timeout in IO operation"

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL workbench to access my database. When i try create the edmx connection in Visual Studio 2012 i get the message "Timeout in IO operation" and i just cant create the model. Someone can help me.

Comment: Can you show some code or other details to illustrate how your trying to make the access?

Answer (score 1):

The probleam was the MySQL for Visual Studio version. I'm was using 1.2.4 and the version that work whit my database version is 1.2.5.

Comment: I know that the post is to old but i wanna say thank you, you are right. I look for the version that work on my database.